# Build Failed on Android studio on different system

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, gradle

The application was working fine but when I imported the project to a different system it is giving the below error -

```
Error:(159, 30) error: incomparable types: Object and int
Error:(166, 35) error: incomparable types: Object and int
Error:(173, 37) error: incomparable types: Object and int
Error:(179, 35) error: incomparable types: Object and int
Error:(185, 35) error: incomparable types: Object and int
Error:(191, 35) error: incomparable types: Object and int
Error:(201, 35) error: incomparable types: Object and int
Error:(207, 35) error: incomparable types: Object and int
Error:(213, 35) error: incomparable types: Object and int
Error:(219, 35) error: incomparable types: Object and int
Error:(369, 35) error: incomparable types: Object and int
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Below is the code in which the error is displaying, The error is being displayed at getTag() -

```
        fragmentDrawer.HideDrawer();


            if(v.getTag()==0)
            {

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

            else if(v.getTag()==1)
            {

                Intent intent=new Intent(context, class2.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

            else   if(v.getTag()==2)
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, class3.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

            else if(v.getTag()==3)
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

            else if(v.getTag()==4)
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, class4.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

            else if(v.getTag()==5)
            {
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,context.getResources().getString(R.string.user_name));
                context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, context.getResources().getString(R.string.about_us)));
            }

            else if(v.getTag()==6)
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, class5.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

            else if(v.getTag()==7)
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, class6.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

            else if(v.getTag()==8)
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, class7.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

            else if(v.getTag()==9)

            {
                dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.rate_us);
                TextView tv_rate_us=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_rate_us);
                TextView tv_tex=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_tex);
                TextView tv_meh = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_meh);
                 LinearLayout ll_loved_it=(LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ll_loved_it);
                LinearLayout ll_meh=(LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ll_meh);
                Fontinnitialize.setFontTextView(tv_tex, context);
                Fontinnitialize.setFontTextViewBold(tv_rate_us, context);
                Fontinnitialize.setFontTextView(tv_meh, context);
                TextView tv_loved_it = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_loved_it);
                Fontinnitialize.setFontTextView(tv_loved_it, context);
                ll_meh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });


            }
        }
    });
```

PS - I have read other posts also related to this but unable to get any solution from that.

Below is the app.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }


    dexOptions {

        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true


    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }




}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.11.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile ('cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: The code as currently posted can never have worked fine on any other system

Answer (score 1):

Change that code to

```
fragmentDrawer.HideDrawer();


        if((Integer)v.getTag()==0)
        {

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

        else if((Integer)v.getTag()==1)
        {

            Intent intent=new Intent(context, class2.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

        else   if((Integer)v.getTag()==2)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, class3.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

        else if((Integer)v.getTag()==3)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

        else if((Integer)v.getTag()==4)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, class4.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

        else if((Integer)v.getTag()==5)
        {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,context.getResources().getString(R.string.user_name));
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, context.getResources().getString(R.string.about_us)));
        }

        else if((Integer)v.getTag()==6)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, class5.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

        else if((Integer)v.getTag()==7)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, class6.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

        else if((Integer)v.getTag()==8)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, class7.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

        else if((Integer)v.getTag()==9)

        {
            dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.rate_us);
            TextView tv_rate_us=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_rate_us);
            TextView tv_tex=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_tex);
            TextView tv_meh = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_meh);
             LinearLayout ll_loved_it=(LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ll_loved_it);
            LinearLayout ll_meh=(LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ll_meh);
            Fontinnitialize.setFontTextView(tv_tex, context);
            Fontinnitialize.setFontTextViewBold(tv_rate_us, context);
            Fontinnitialize.setFontTextView(tv_meh, context);
            TextView tv_loved_it = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_loved_it);
            Fontinnitialize.setFontTextView(tv_loved_it, context);
            ll_meh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


        }
    }
});
```

Beacuse the v.getTag() return Object we have to type cast it to Integer. otherwise you get an error 
hope this will help